# Sinon error Attempted to wrap function which is already wrapped

Tags: node.js, sinon

Though there is a same question here but I could not find answer to my problem so here goes my question:

I am testing my node js app using mocha and chai. I am using sinion to wrap my function.

```
describe('App Functions', function(){

  let mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', (dbUrl) => {
     //some stuff
  });
  it('get results',function(done) {
     testApp.someFun
  });
}

describe('App Errors', function(){

  let mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', (dbUrl) => {
     //some stuff
  });
  it('throws errors',function(done) {
     testApp.someFun
  });
}
```

When I try to run this test it gives me error

```
Attempted to wrap getObj which is already wrapped
```

I also tried putting

```
beforeEach(function () {
  sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
});

afterEach(function () {
  sandbox.restore();
});
```

in each describe, but still giving me same error.

Comment: You can find an explanation at the bottom of the post [here](https://medium.com/@alfasin/stubbing-with-sinon-4d6539caf365)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You should restore the `getObj` in `after()` function, please try it as below.

```
describe('App Functions', function(){
    var mockObj;
    before(function () {
            mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', () => {
                 console.log('this is sinon test 1111');
            });
    });

    after(function () {
        testApp.getObj.restore(); // Unwraps the spy
    });

    it('get results',function(done) {
        testApp.getObj();
    });
});

describe('App Errors', function(){
    var mockObj;
    before(function () {
            mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', () => {
                 console.log('this is sinon test 1111');
            });
    });

    after( function () {
        testApp.getObj.restore(); // Unwraps the spy
    });

    it('throws errors',function(done) {
         testApp.getObj();
    });
});
```

### Update 2022/01/22

Using [sinon's sanbox](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/sandbox/) you could created stub mocks with `sandbox.stub()` and restores all fakes created through `sandbox.restore()`, Arjun Malik give an good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550827/3011380)

Comment: After trying the above accepted way, I am getting the same error under "before all" hook

Comment: @AshwinHegde, could you please give me your test codes? Maybe I can find some issue here.

Comment: Is there no way to restore all stubs without specifying each one? Would be great to have a `sinon.restoreAll();` that could be run after all tests just to make sure you don't forget to restore a stub.

Comment: afterEach(()=> {
        sinon.verifyAndRestore();
 });

Comment: Using sinon's sanbox you could created stub with `sandbox.stub(...)` and restore everything later with just `sandbox.restore()`

Answer (score 45):

This error is due to not restoring the stub function properly. Use sandbox and then create the stub using the sandbox. After each test inside the suite, restore the sandbox

```
  beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      mockObj = sandbox.stub(testApp, 'getObj', fake_function)
  });

  afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
  });
```

Comment: dude, saved my life)

Comment: This worked for me.  I feel like this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I had multiple tests with wrapping functions and need to use **afterEach**.

Comment: In my case, this was the correct answer, since I was spying a whole object and not a specific method, so I couldn't restore.

Answer (score 12):

For cases where you need to restore all the methods of one object, you can use the `sinon.restore(obj)`.

**Example:**

```
before(() => {
    userRepositoryMock = sinon.stub(userRepository);
});

after(() => {
    sinon.restore(userRepository);
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when stubbing functions on the object. I had to restore per function like the accepted answer shows.

Comment: sinon.restore() was deprecated in Sinon v2 and removed afterwards.

`// Previously
sinon.restore(stubObject);

// Typescript
(stubObject as any).restore();

// Javascript
stubObject.restore();`

Comment: calling sinon.restore() inside afterEach() solved this issue, sinon version installed is 5.1.1

Answer (score 9):

Just a heads-up, because this took me about an hour to figure out:

If you have two (or more) test files, and find yourself **still** getting "already wrapped" error no matter what you try, make sure your `beforeEach` and `afterEach`  stub / replace handlers are INSIDE the test file's `describe` block.

If you put them in the global test scope, i.e. OUTSIDE the `describe('my test description', () => {})` construct, sinon will attempt it twice and throw this.

Comment: highly underrated answer

Answer (score 8):

I was also hitting this using the before() and after() hooks of Mocha. I was also using the restore() as mentioned everywhere. Single test file ran fine, multiple did not. 
Finally found about [Mocha root-level-hooks](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks): I did not have my before() and after() inside my own describe(). So it finds all files with before() at the root-level and executes those before starting any tests.

So make sure you have a similar pattern:

```
describe('my own describe', () => {
  before(() => {
    // setup stub code here
    sinon.stub(myObj, 'myFunc').callsFake(() => {
      return 'bla';
    });
  });
  after(() => {
    myObj.myFunc.restore();
  });
  it('Do some testing now', () => {
    expect(myObj.myFunc()).to.be.equal('bla');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone running into this issue, if you stub or spy on the entire object, and you later do

> sandbox.restore()

You'll still get the error. You have to stub/spy the individual methods.

I wasted forever trying to figure out what was wrong.

sinon-7.5.0

Answer (score 3):

It is advised to initialize stubs in 'beforeEach' and restore them in 'afterEach'. But in case you are feeling adventurous, the following works too.

```
describe('App Functions', function(){

  let mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', (dbUrl) => {
     //some stuff
  });
  it('get results',function(done) {
     testApp.someFun
     mockObj .restore();
  });
}

describe('App Errors', function(){

  let mockObj = sinon.stub(testApp, 'getObj', (dbUrl) => {
     //some stuff
  });
  it('throws errors',function(done) {
     testApp.someFun
     mockObj .restore();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Even with sandbox it could give you the error. Especially when tests run in parallel for ES6 classes.

```
const sb = sandbox.create();

before(() => {
  sb.stub(MyObj.prototype, 'myFunc').callsFake(() => {
    return 'whatever';
  });
});
after(() => {
  sb.restore();
});
```

this could throw the same error if another test is trying to stub myFunc from the Prototype.
I was able to fix that but I am not proud of it...

```
const sb = sandbox.create();

before(() => {
  MyObj.prototype.myFunc = sb.stub().callsFake(() => {
    return 'whatever';
  });
});
after(() => {
  sb.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this with spies. This behaviour makes sinon pretty inflexible to work with. I created a helper function that attempts to remove any existing spy before setting a new one. That way I don't have to worry about any before/after state. A similar approach might work for stubs too.

```js
import sinon, { SinonSpy } from 'sinon';

/**
 * When you set a spy on a method that already had one set in a previous test,
 * sinon throws an "Attempted to wrap [function] which is already wrapped" error
 * rather than replacing the existing spy. This helper function does exactly that.
 *
 * @param {object} obj
 * @param {string} method
 */
export const spy = function spy<T>(obj: T, method: keyof T): SinonSpy {
  // try to remove any existing spy in case it exists
  try {
    // @ts-ignore
    obj[method].restore();
  } catch (e) {
    // noop
  }
  return sinon.spy(obj, method);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this behavior because the function was spy-ed somewhere else. So, I removed the predefined spy like below and created my own.

```js
obj.func.restore()
let spy = sinon.spy(obj, 'func')
```

It works.

Answer (score -1):

```
function stub(obj, method) {
     // try to remove any existing stub in case it exists
      try {
        obj[method].restore();
      } catch (e) {
        // eat it.
      }
      return sinon.stub(obj, method);
    }
```

and use this function when creating stubs in tests. It will resolve 'Sinon error Attempted to wrap function which is already wrapped' error.

example:

```
stub(Validator.prototype, 'canGeneratePayment').returns(Promise.resolve({ indent: dTruckIndent }));
```